Significant performance difference in django view vs. django shell within docker
I'm encountering a significant performance difference when running the same raw SQL query in my Django application. The query executes in about 0.5 seconds in the Django shell but takes around 2 seconds when called from a Django view. Both are running in an isolated Docker container environment. I've isolated the query execution into a function execute_query() used in both contexts, disabled DEBUG, and attempted to disable transactions with no improvement. Here's the function:
def execute_query():
    st = time.time()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT 
            cars.created_at, 
            cars.owner_id, 
            cars.status, 
            cars.color, 
            cars.type, 
            owners.source 
        FROM cars 
        INNER JOIN owners 
            ON cars.owner_id = owners.id 
        WHERE 
            owners.membership_id = 'example_id' 
            AND cars.created_at BETWEEN '2022-07-15 23:59:59' AND '2025-09-14 00:00:00' 
            AND cars.is_active = False 
            AND cars.description IS NOT NULL 
            AND cars.type != 'electric' 
        LIMIT 50000
    """)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Query took: {end - st} seconds")
    return end - st

I am wondering what might be causing the performance differences mentioned above.
